# How to configure Azure DevOps Boards Sprits for teams in a hierarchy?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to integrate many of our teams into Azure DevOps Boards, currently one project has the following teams:

- Front-end
- Back-end
- Design

Many of the User Stories will be shared between teams, for example a Login screen will be designed by the Design team and coded by the front-end and back-end teams.

I have set-up a Management team and placed the others teams under it. I created one iteration too, "Sprint 1".

I then created a User Story for the Login under the Management Area Path. Then I created a Task for that User Story and attributed it for the Mobile team Area Path.

I was expecting to see a Login User Story with Front-end and Back-end Tasks. This works on the Backlog board but not on the Taksboard.

In the Management Taksboard I can't see the Mobile Tasks, and in the Mobile team's Taksboard all tasks appear as "unparented" (even though they have a parent and I can see the parent as link of the Task).

How do we configure Sprints in Azure DevOps Boards for hierarchal work items that span multiple teams?